# How to detect stop loss, when strategy.exit(loss=n)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have strategy.exit() which includes a loss condition. I wish to execute something upon its triggering. Is there en event generated by strategy.exit(loss=n) that I can use to trigger my functions? Shall I only use price as my trigger?

I wanted to make it cleaner, but indeed I could use `close<longStopPrice and position_size == 0`

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no event triggered.

What you can do is something like:

```
is_long_trade_closed = (strategy.position_size[1] > 0) and (strategy.position_size == 0)
was_long_sl_hit = low[1] <= longStopPrice
is_long_sl_hit = is_long_trade_closed and was_long_sl_hit
```